# How to find record from a very big HIVE table where column header__timestamp,header__change_seq should be latest update and id should unique

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql

I have to find record from the hive table where Id, der__timestamp, header__change_seq should be unique but in table (Id, der__timestamp, header__change_seq) can duplicate so in this case i have to fetch only one record if records are getting duplicate .

```
    select b.* 
    from (SELECT ID, max(COALESCE(header__timestamp)) 
    max_modified,MAX(CAST(header__change_seq AS DECIMAL(38,0))) max_sequence 
    FROM table_name group by ID) a
    join table_name b on (a.id=b.id and 
    a.max_modified=b.header__timestamp and 
    a.max_sequence=b.header__change_seq)
```

So the total number of distinct id is count-->244441250
but through above query i am getting  count-->244442548
due to some duplicate records but i have to find only distinct id where (header__change_seq and header__timestamp) should max .

Comment: show some sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

@Rahul; please try this one. It makes use of row_number() so in case of duplicate id, header_timestamp and hearder_change_seq, it will select only one record. Hope it helps.

```
select * 
from (
select *,
row_number() over ( partition by id order by header__timestamp desc, header__change_seq desc) as rnk 
from table_name) t
where t.rnk = 1;
```